# deploy build to artifactory via cli or jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, deployment, build, artifactory

```
./jfrog rt upload --url http://192.168.1.10:8081/artifactory/ --user=admin --password=password --build-name=ttt --build-number=70 1.txt ttt/my/txttest/1.0.1/txttest-1.0.1.txt
./jfrog rt bce ttt 70
./jfrog rt build-publish ttt 70
```

Look at artifactory and see grey link (unworking) to published artifacts in build tab.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkz5b.png)

Artifacts are normally uploaded and accessible.
Same will happen then use "Generic-Artifactory Integration" from Jenkins

Artifactory OSS 5.5.2 rev 50502900

./jfrog version 1.12.1

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs managing artifacts for builds isn't available in OSS editions. See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Comparison+Matrix

Comment: Let me see if I got this right, So you can publish the artifacts from the build and you can publish information for a build. However, you cannot access the artifacts from the Published Modules section?